# Search Bar ResignFirstResponder hides Items

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, resignfirstresponder

I have this search bar in my app [image] Please see the play, next and previous buttons.

When I search and click on a song from the search items resigning first responder for search bar hides my buttons i.e play, next and previous buttons.

[image]

I am using this code

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
MPMediaItem * song;
_nowPlayingIndex=indexPath.row;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    song = searchResults[_nowPlayingIndex];
else
    song = _songs[_nowPlayingIndex];

[self.musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:song];
[self.musicPlayer play];
_playButton.hidden=true;
_pauseButton.hidden=false;

[_mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Why are my buttons hidden?

Comment: Select your buttons view and set AutoSizing Mask  Enable left, right, top and center position.

Comment: i have already done the AutoSizing.@karthi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : What you can do is make a different function for showing and hiding these buttons or any other item.

Step 2 : You can then call these functions wherever required. e.g. Everytime after you have resigned the responder.

Step 3 : You can try setting the table view frame to some less height from code. And then test this thing. Because I think the height of your table view leads to the hiding of those buttons.
e.g. `[self.tableView setFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.searchSong.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - "button.height" - "navbar.height")];`

Step 4 : Also you should debug your code as to when you execute the resignFirstResponder... please check what is the frame of your buttons. This way you will get to know their position.

Its just another way of solving your issue. If you still have questions, you can ask. I hope it works. :)

Comment: No luck @believe_anky its not working.I have no idea why are my buttons hidden. At least my code should show the previous and next buttons.

Comment: You mean table view of the displayController?How can i do that?

Comment: You can try setting the table view frame to some less height from code. And then test this thing. Because I think the height of your table view leads to the hiding of those buttons.

Comment: Also you should debug your code as to when you execute the `resignFirstResponder`... please check what is the frame of your buttons. This way you will get to know their position.

Comment: Yeah i got it now the reason why my buttons are hidden.can u provide some sample code?

Comment: Now i got another issue...my buttons wont work now :(@believe_anky

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36254/discussion-between-believe-anky-and-machete)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i was looking for

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
CGRect tableFrame= self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height=200;
tableFrame.size.width=300;
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setFrame:tableFrame];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

}

and this [[myButton superview] bringSubviewToFront:myButton]; for bringing them to front.

Answer (score 0):

when you search anything apply code to your buttons is search delegate

```
 [grayBar bringSubViewToFront];
```

or

```
 [yourButton1 bringSubViewToFront];
 [yourButton2 bringSubViewToFront];
 [yourButton3 bringSubViewToFront];
```

hope this helps